# Problem in designing a shell in C to execute commands connected by logical and

Tags: c, linux, shell, exec

I was writing a simple shell in C to execute external commands like `command1 & command2` and here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

static char line[1024];
char *and, *or, *col;
char *arg[1024];

static char* skipwhite(char* s)
{
        while (isspace(*s)) ++s;
        return s;
}
void run(char *cmd)
{
        *and='\0';
        int stat;
        cmd= skipwhite(cmd);
        char *next= strchr(cmd, ' ');
        int i=0;
        printf("%s \n", cmd);

        while(next!=NULL)
        {
                *next='\0';
                arg[i]=cmd;:
                i++;
                cmd= skipwhite(next+1);
                next= strchr(cmd, ' ');
        }
        //arg[i]='\0';

        int shmid =  shmget(66, sizeof(int), IPC_CREAT | 0777);
        int *status=(int *)shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
        *status=1;

        int pid=fork();
        if(pid==0)
        {
                int *v=(int *)shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
                if(execvp(arg[0], arg)==-1)
                {
                        *v=0;
                        _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
        }
        else
        {
                        waitpid(pid, &stat, 0);
                        if(*status==0)
                                exit(0);
                        //printf("Trying to execute 2nd command\n");
                        cmd=and+1;
                        printf("%s \n", cmd);
                        and = strchr(cmd, '&');
                        if(and==NULL)
                        {
                                cmd= skipwhite(cmd);
                                next = strchr(cmd, ' ');
                                i=0;
                                while(next!=NULL)
                                {
                                        *next='\0';
                                        arg[i]=cmd;
                                        i++;
                                        cmd= skipwhite(next+1);
                                        next= strchr(cmd, ' ');
                                }
                                arg[i]=cmd;
                                //arg[i+1]='\0';

                                if(execvp(arg[0], arg)==-1)
                                        _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                                return;
                        }
                        else
                                run(cmd);
        }
}

int main()
{

        int status, pid;
        printf("SIMPLE SHELL made by me. Type 'exit' or send EOF to exit.\n");

        while(1)
        {
                printf("$> ");
                fflush(NULL);

                if(!fgets(line, 1024, stdin))
                        return 0;

                char *cmds= line;
                if(strcmp(cmds, "exit")==0)
                        exit(0);
                and= strchr(cmds, '&');
                or= strchr(cmds, '|');
                col= strchr(cmds, ';');

                if(and!=NULL)
                {
                        pid=fork();
                        if(pid==0)
                                run(cmds);
                        else
                                waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
                }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

My motivation is :

Whenever shell receives an external command, it forks itself, say the new process is 1 and the command is `command1 & command2`. 1 again forks itself for executing command1 and command2. If `command1` is successfully executed, then only a new process for `command2` is created else not.

The problem is , the last command is never executed even if it is a correct one. I cannot figure out the problem in the code.

If any information required, please drop a comment below.

Comment: You don't have a path handling command lines without a `&` and you handle the last command differently than the initial ones. This requires extry synching effort to keep both code parts identical. There should be some more generic way to handle any number of `&` in the command line.

Comment: @Gerhardh Yes you are right, I need to generalise, but as a good start I chose a specific set of command. I will gradually develop more generic functions. I am studying Linux OS now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this loop

```
        while(next!=NULL)
        {
                *next='\0';
                arg[i]=cmd;:
                i++;
                cmd= skipwhite(next+1);
                next= strchr(cmd, ' ');
        }
        //arg[i]='\0';
```

You copy all parts of the string into `arg` except the last.

For the last token in your command line you get a valid pointer to `cmd` but `NULL` for `next` if there is no extra space after the token, leaving this token unhandled.

You also commented out the sentinel for the `arg` array which is required for `execv` family of functions.

You might rework the loop:

```
        while(cmd && *cmd) {
            arg[i++]=cmd;
            if (next) {
                *next='\0';
                cmd = skipwhite(next+1);
                next = strchr(cmd, ' ');
            }
            else {
                cmd = NULL;        
            }
        }
        arg[i]='\0';
```

Update regarding extra question:

You have a `'\n'` at the end of your command because you don't chop it after reading the command line.
Function `fgets` reads the whole line into the buffer, up to (and including) the the `'\n'` it the buffer is large enough.

You simply need to remove it immediately after calling `fgets`:

```
               size_t len = strlen(line);
               if (line[len-1] == '\n')
                        line[len-1] = 0;
```

or

```
               line[strlen(line)-1] = 0;
```

The first version also works fine if you enter 1023 characters for your commands where the `'\n'` cannot be stored in the buffer.

The second version only works fine if you enter less than 1023 characters. For a maximum length command it will kill the last character.

Comment: My command is `ls -l & ls -i` . The array is filling correctly, i.e., `arg[0]='ls'` , `arg[1]='-i'` , `arg[2]=NULL`, but `\n` is getting added with `-i` at the end. This is the reason why `execvp` is still failing. What is the cause of newline character getting added? How to get rid of it?

Comment: This is how `fgets` is defined to work. If you don't want it, chop it. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help and the explanation.